# Modelling API: each row represents a table. Suggestions?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, loopbackjs

I have an app that stores user uploaded spreadsheets as tables in PostgreSQL. Everytime an user uploads a spreadsheet I create a record in a `Dataset` table containing the physical table name, its alias and the owner. I can retrieve a certain Dataset information with

```
GET domain.com/v1/Datasets/{id}
```

AFAIK, the relation between rows in `Dataset` and physical tables can't be enforced by a FK, or at least I haven't seen anyones creating FKs on the information_schema of PostgreSQL, **and FKs can't drop tables**, or can they? So it's common to have orphan tables, or records in  `Dataset`  that point to tables that no longer exist. I have managed this with business logic and cleaning tasks.

Now, to access one of those physical tables, for example one called `nba_teams` I would need to declare an NbaTeams model in loopback and restart the app, then query its records with

```
GET domain.com/v1/NbaTeams/{id}
```

But that can't scale, specially if I'm already having like 100 uploads a day. So from where I'm standing, there are two ways to go:

1.- Create one model, then add 4 custom methods that accepts a table name as a string, and perform the next CRUD operation on that table name via raw queries. For example, to list the records:

```
GET domain.com/v1/Datasets/getTable/NbaTeams
```

or, to update one team

```
PUT domain.com/v1/Datasets/getTable/NbaTeams/{teamId}
```

This sounds unelegant but should work.

2.- Create a custom method that accepts a table name as a string, which in turn creates an ephemeral model and forward the HTTP verb and the rest of the arguments to it

```
dataSource.discoverAndBuildModels('nba_teams', {
    owner: 'uploader'
}, function (err, models) {
    console.log(models);
    models.NbaTeams.find(function (err, act) {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
        } else {
            console.log(act);
        }
        dataSource.disconnect();
    });
});
```

this second one I haven't got to work yet, and I don't know how much overhead it might have, but I'm sure it's doable.

So before I dig in deeper I came to ask: **has anybody dealt with this row-to-table relation**? **What are the good practices in this**?

Comment: Hi @CraigRinger. [LoopBack](http://docs.strongloop.com/display/LB/LoopBack+2.0) is a framework by StrongLoop. It provides a restful api for user defined models, a loosely coupled ORM (that you might use along with the API, altought is not required) and datasource connectors for postgres, mysql and mongo (among others). 

The main APP (the one where you upload spreadsheets) uses Doctrine as the ORM, but I wanted to explore a lighter endpoint to provide just CRUD over the already uploaded spreadsheets. That why I got to loopback.

Comment: OK, that makes more sense. I've fixed the tags to refer to [tag:loopbackjs] instead of [tag:loopback]. (Removing now-irrelevant original comment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, I did my own hacky workaround and I thought it may help someone, some day.

What I did was put a middleware (with regular express syntax) to listen for /v1/dataset{id_dataset} , create the model on the fly and pass the execution to the next middleware

```
app.use('/v1/dataset:id_dataset', function(req, res, next) {
    var idDataset=req.params.id_dataset;
    app.getTheTable(idDataset,function(err,result) {
        if(err) { 
          console.error(err);
          res.json({"error":"couldn't retrieve related table"});
        } else {
          next();
        }
    });
});
```

inside the `app.getTheTable` function, I'm creating a model dynamically and setting it up before callback

```
app.getTheTable = function (idDataset, callback) {
    var Table = app.models.Dataset,
    modelName='dataset'+idDataset,
    dataSource;

    Table.findById(idDataset, function (err, resultados) {
        if (err) {
            callback(new Error('Unauthorized'));
        } else {
           if(app.models[modelName]) {
               callback(null,modelName); // model already exists
           } else {
               var theDataset = dataSource.createModel(modelName, properties, options);
               theDataset.settings.plural = modelName;
               theDataset.setup();

               app.model(theDataset);
               var restApiRoot = app.get('restApiRoot');
               app.use(restApiRoot, app.loopback.rest());

               callback(null, modelName);
           }
        }
    });
};
```

It's hacky, I know, and I believe there must be some kind of performance penalty for overloading restApiRoot middleware, but it's still better tan creating 500 models on startup to cover all possible dataset requests.